# Rcpp Armadillo package compilation "error: incorrect or unsupported type" when trying to convert a

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have the latest version of R, RCppArmadillo and RStudio installed. I started a brand new R project using Rcpp with Armadillo, and created a single new cpp file called rcpparma_basic.cpp.

This is the content of that file:

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec rcpparma_head(arma::rowvec x, int n) {

    Rcpp::IntegerVector first_rcpp = Rcpp::IntegerVector::create(0,1,2);
    arma::uvec first(first_rcpp); // instantiate the armadillo vec from the Rcpp vec

    arma::rowvec out = x.elem(first);
    return out;
}
```

I thought it would be possible for me to convert the integer vector obtained from Rcpp into an arma vec, based on the example Dirk Eddelbuettel provided in his answer on this page:

[How can I multiply an Armadillo matrix with a NumericVector obtained from qnorm()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641766/how-can-i-multiply-an-armadillo-matrix-with-a-numericvector-obtained-from-qnorm)

The reason I was trying to convert Rcpp IntegerVector to arma vec is that I wanted to be able to use the Rcpp seq function, and related functions, along with arma objects.

But when I try to compile the package, it fails with an error at this line in Mat_meat.h:

```
static_assert( is_same_type< eT, rcpp_type >::value , "error: incorrect or unsupported type" );
```

I am not suggesting the error is in Mat_meat.h, I'm sure I've got something wrong in my code, but based on that error message I have no idea what that mistake might be. So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Louise

Comment: Your function is not making sense to me. Since you would like to use `arma::uvec`, why not just do this `arma::uvec first_rcpp = {0,1,2};` Why do you want to do type conversion in this case? Also, note that `unsigned int` is not a supported type in Rcpp since R does not support it. As such, there is no defined constructor for you to use. You could use `arma::ivec` and then use `arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from` arrive at the type you need, but I don't see the point in taking such a detour.

Comment: "_The reason I was trying to convert Rcpp IntegerVector to arma vec is that I wanted to be able to use the Rcpp seq function_" is also not a well-established reason. Take note of the [`linspace`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#linspace) function and read Armadillo's documentation.

Comment: You have five lines of statements in your code (also counting the signature).  As @ekoam pointed out, the logical flow of what you are trying to do is not clear, You recognise you have an error so what I would do here is to _simplify_.  Try passing an object in and print.  Try passing an object out.  Try modifying one. As the saying goes:  _Try to walk before you run_.  There are hundreds of working examples on this site alone, then there is CRAN, the Rcpp Gallery, GitHub, and much more.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a partial answer to what I was doing wrong: when I wrap the output of the Rcpp seq function, then I stop getting the Mat_meat.h error and get more informative errors.

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec rcpparma_head(arma::rowvec x, int n) {

    Rcpp::IntegerVector first_rcpp = Rcpp::IntegerVector::create(0,1,2);
    arma::uvec first(Rcpp::wrap(first_rcpp)); // instantiate the armadillo vec from the Rcpp vec

    arma::rowvec out = x.elem(first);
    return out;
}
```

Then the errors I get are both for that wrap line and say "No matching function for call to arma::Col ::Col(SEXP)" and "invalid conversion from 'SEXP' {aka 'SEXPREC*'} to 'arma::uword' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]".

So at least now I'm getting more useful errors.

I was only trying to recreate a head() function in Rcpp as a mini practice function to clarify some of the arma/Rcpp rules for myself before moving on to a more complex function I need for my package. Given the fact that there seem to be more useful functions for me in Rcpp than in Armadillo, and the fact that the latest version of my algorithm no longer uses matrix algebra because the inner model doesn't allow it, I think I'll just stop using Armadillo.